# Basic Probability blood types

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I just want to confirm this. $ p(A \cap$ B) is not mutually exclusive since the event AB is able to occur. However $P(O\cap B)$ can not occur because there is no event OB.

Here is how I am thinking of  $ p(A \cap$ B)[image]

Comment: I think it's something about biology-AB is another blood group, doesn't mean that one is A and B simultaneously.

Comment: The fact that the numbers add up to $20$ and this is the number given under "Total" also seems to indicate that these events are intended to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: You should think of $AB$ simply as blood type $C$, a completely different blood type, not as an intersection of $A$ and $B$

Comment: Before anybody can give you a correct answer to this you will need to specify whether one person is selected randomly from the 20 people who attended the Red Cross center, or whether one person was selected from the population to which the 20 belong.

Answer (score 2):

As @user3313321 commented, type AB here has nothing to do with types A or B; they're mutually exclusive. So, the probabilities are pretty simple:

- Probability of type AB is 3 in 20, or 15%
- Probability of type A or type B is 10 in 20, or 50%
- Probability of both type O and B: zero in 20, or 0%
- Probability of not type 0: (20 - 7) in 20, or 65%
- Probability of type A given that is not type O: 4 in (20 - 7), or ~31%

(That last question was a bit strangely worded; it took a hint from Mr. Stork before I understood it.)

Comment: Daniel Griscom's answer to the last question is incorrect.  The probability of "A given that that the blood is not O" is 4/13, not 4/20.  There are only *13* cases that are "not O", and that is the denominator of your probability.  [I also assume the [1] and [2] are the number of points you'll receive on this part of the homework problem.]

Comment: Ah: that's what they were trying to say. I'll rewrite my answer. (Thanks.)